# JQuery $.ajax post does not work with IE10 but works with IE 8 and other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-10

`$.ajax` with post request is not working with IE 10 but works with IE 8 an all other browsers.
Code:

**Edit:** 
I am using following jquery version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="../js/jquery-1.8.2.js" />"></script>

var eventName = $("#name").val();
var description = $("#description").val();
var location = $("#location").val();
var date = $("#date").val();
var startTime = $("#startTime").val();
var endTime = $("#endTime").val();
var status = $("#status").val();

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'createEvent',
    data:{
          "groupID": '${groupID}',
          "name": eventName,
          "description": description,
          "location": location,
          "date": date,
          "startTime": startTime,
          "endTime": endTime,
          "status": status
    },
        success:function(result){
               alert('Success');
        }
});
```

While getting value in back end I am getting null value for each parameter. But submitting from other browser and even in IE 8 it works fine.

What could be the problem and how to solve this ? please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining those variables? What version of jQuery? We need to see more code.

Comment: Have you tried using the console in IE10, it should show a javascript error if there's a problem somewhere

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery? Other than that, your code looks fine, w/out more details, this is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @Gerve In console I am getting 500 error.

Comment: @BradM The top line of his code now has version 1.8.2 after the edits.

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi A 500 error is a back-end code error, not front-end. There's probably a helpful stack trace in some error logs or in the network traffic of the IE dev tools.

Comment: @BradM I tried latest <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> too but does not work, the param value is showing null in back end server...

Comment: Are you sure setting the window location to a HTML element is a good idea ?

Comment: @adeneo That is the server code, not the exact rendered html.

Comment: @ajp15243 I think that 500 error is due to interruption in server side. The parameter value is getting null while fetching it in server. Ajax calls the url but does not send the value

Comment: @adeneo actully I just wanted to work in success part it is use less there. Thanks. any help to tackle this problem please

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi Can you post the rendered javascript as it appears on the page, instead of the source code?

Comment: In the IE console, click *Network*, *Start Capturing*, then cause your post request to happen. double click the post request, then inspect the Response Headers. Is the data being sent? If not, console.dir() the data object before sending the post request.

Comment: @BradM Due to reputation limit I could not attach image. I am getting Content-length : 0 in console, does it mean anything

Comment: @KevinB I checked in Response Headers which displays: Key Value
Response HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type text/html;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Date Thu, 13 Jun 2013 17:23:00 GMT
Connection close. I think date is not being sent. Can you help me ?

Comment: you need Request headers, not response. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @KevinB In Request headers there is "Content-Length 0" does it mean anything. Yes I want to check whether the data is sent to server or not how to do that ?

Comment: In Request Body there is no data ? What is the cause please.

Comment: Your data object may possibly be malformed so the request isn't sent `Content-Length 0`. Send your data values to debugger console to see the differences between browsers: `var dataObj = { groupID: '${groupID}', name: eventName, ...}; console.log(dataObj);`

Comment: @Jasen Yes, in other browser in console Object {groupID: "84", name: "lll", description: "", location: "", date: "13 Jun, 13"…} but IN ie 10 print [object Object]. Any help please

Comment: May need to `JSON.stringify(dataObj)` to see that in IE

Comment: @Jasen Yes you r right, after doing this 'JSON.stringify(dataObj)' prints correctly in console, so I can i pass it to data? Thanks

Comment: @Jasen I think you can help me, please suggest me how to pass variable as a data object after doing `JSON.stringify(dataObj)`

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi you would `$.ajax({ ... , data: dataObj })`

Comment: @Jasen I tried it too but not working... :(

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is and you don't have rep to enter chat so... Some things to help you debug this: 1) clear the browser cache 2) try removing some data fields you are trying to pass until it's successful 3) set data fields to empty strings 4) show us the data you're trying to post

Comment: I have tried everything I can, I am doing this since 5/6 hours. Request body says `No data to view`. I passed the data for each parameter i.e. {groupID :1, ...} but not working. Only says `No data to view` in ie 10 console